# C# - Casting a Reflection.PropertyInfo object to its Type

Tags: c#, reflection

In my application, I have a `Reflection.PropertyInfo` variable named 'property'. When I do a `property.GetValue(myObject,null)`, the value is `Master.Enterprise`. Enterprise is a class in my application. So, 'property' contains a reference to a class in my app.

At runtime, I would like to somehow cast 'property' to its type (`Master.Enterprise`) so I can use it as if it were the class type.

I know this can be done because when I look at the code in the debugger, the debugger correctly casts 'property' to the type its referencing, and I can see all the properties of the Enterprise class in the debugger.

How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Actually, the debugger *doesn't* *really* cast it to the property type - it simply reports on the object via reflection. The object knows that it *is* an `Enterprise` object.

Comment: If you want to work with it "as if it were the class type", you need to know what it could be - so you could just try casting the object or see if it is what you want with the `is` operator. If you do not know what it could be, you cannot work with it anyways, right?

Comment: I agree with hangy. Your question is unclear. The object returned by `property.GetValue` has a well-defined runtime type. What do you mean by 'use it as if it were the class type'? Provide some examples of what kind of use are you envisioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string of the Type Name you can do something like this:

```
Assembly execAsm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
object instance = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(execAsm.FullName, "RipperWorkbench.Classes.LoadManager"); // the type name cam come from a variable or someplace else.
```

then you can cast it to the type you need

```
Master.Enterprise ent = obj as Master.Enterprise;
if (obj != null) 
{
     ...
}
```

Or alternatively, have the object implement an interface:
You have to be sure that the type is loaded into current AppDomain, otherwise the type can't be reflected.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

// The executing assembly can change also; so you can load types from other assemblies
// use this if the type isn't loaded in this AppDomain yet.
//Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile("path to assembly here", new Evidence());

String typeToLoad = "Master.Enterprise"; // this can be from a config or database call
Type objType = asm.GetType(typeToLoad, true);

if (!objType.IsPublic)
return null;

// make sure the type isn't Abstract
if (((objType.Attributes & TypeAttributes.Abstract) == TypeAttributes.Abstract))
    return null;

// IEnterprise is the interface that all of the plugin types must implement to be loaded
Type objInterface = objType.GetInterface("IEnterprise", true);

if (objInterface == null)
    return null;

    var iri = (IEnterprise)Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
    return iri;
```

Answer (score 5):

It sounds to me like you need to define an interface - you can then require that your property returns an object that implements that interface, and you will then be able to cast into that interface regardless of what class implements that interface:

```
IEnterprise enterprise = (IEnterprise)property.GetValue(myObject, null);
```

The only other option you have is to call methods and properties on the returned object using reflection - this is what the visual studio debugger is doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
Master.Enterprise enterprise = (Master.Enterprise)property.GetValue(myObject,null);
```

or

```
Master.Enterprise enterprise = property.GetValue(myObject,null) as Master.Enterprise;
```

The first will throw an exception if the type is not compatible.  The second will return null if not compatible.

Comment: Thank you but this isn't going to work. Remember, I don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: @Randy: if you don't know the type (or at least the *possible* types) at compile time, i.e., in the code you're writing, how are you going to use it?

Comment: If you don't know what type it is, how will you know how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

In the future you can use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736(VS.100).aspx). For now I think you should [use the solution with the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783028/c-casting-a-reflection-propertyinfo-object-to-its-type/1783337#1783337).

Answer (score 2):

If the type is unknown at compile time and you can't assume it implements an interface that IS known, you can't cast it to that type because c# is a statically typed language.

You'll be able to do this with c# 4.0 if you want to wait for it/use the beta, something like:

```
dynamic obj=property.GetValue(myObject,null);
obj.CallSomeMethod();
```

Note however that will internally just call reflection methods to figure out how to do that. You can do that today by extensive reflection calls yourself. If you give us more information about what specifically you want to do with that returned object, I'll be able to give you a more detailed answer.